# Remote Desktop listen on 2 different ports

Tags: port, remote-desktop

I have a server which in the local network I would like to access remotely through the default RDP port 3389.

Due to filtering services at work, the port 3389 is unavailable as many other ports. Because I do not use the SMTP port 25, I would like to use that port to listen with RDP but at the same time keep it listening on 3389 for local purposes.

Is this possible to achieve and if so, how? Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because, as with your MySQL question, you're tying to subvert a local security policy. If there are filters in place, they're probably for a good reason. Your best bet is to try to convince your IT department off your need get them to change it. 

Comment: Which OS is this? You can add a 2nd binding on a different port with different security settings, but it requires a second network connection. I frown upon bypassing local security policies though.

Comment: The OS is Windows Server 2008 R2 and on the note of @SmallClanger 's comment, it isn't a security policy, its a bug in their server infrastructure causing various ports to be blocked. They have been trying to diagnose for weeks as to what the problem could be but so far haven't found anything, hence why I am trying to put services on the few (5) open ports that I could find that go to my server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it by editing registry key. Before editing, you should backup your registry, or export only key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\RDP-Tcp`

Then:

- Edit export file above
- Change it to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal
  Server\WinStations\RDP-Tcp-NewName ( i.e RDP-Tcp-1111 )
- Change `PortNumber` to port you want ( hexa value )
- Import it to registry and restart server

Comment: This will *change* the port, but not add one

Comment: @Mark Henderson: Edited.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do that! Talk to your security guys and ask if you can use RD or not. You can't just ignore the security policy rules and misuse the ports like that. It's a big security hole especially when the only aware person is you

Comment: There's actually something wrong with the networking infrastructure which is blocking lots of ports. It's odd cause it varies depending on the host. They have been on it for weeks and still haven't found the cause hence why I have done a port scan and attempting to assign ports to unused services I have.