# RDP Rights in Windows Server 2019

Tags: windows, rdp

Good day! In this [topic](https://serverfault.com/questions/528639/remote-desktop-listen-on-2-different-ports/528642), I read that you can have two independent RDP connections, this works, but the question is how to give separate rights to each of them in order to distinguish between

I have a Windows Server 2019 server, I created two RDP connections on ports 3389 and 3390. According to the instructions, I registered the [Tsconfig.msc snap-in](http://pyatilistnik.org/tsconfig-msc-and-tsadmin-msc-on-windows-server-2019/), but I can’t assign the rights, someone can tell me, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking about this the wrong way around. User accounts and their associated rights should be personal. If you need to have multiple users connect with different access rights, set up separate user accounts and assign permissions as required.

Protip: Make it a habit to create groups to which you assign permissions. Then add users to the relevant groups depending on what they need to work on. Always assign the lowest permissions required for a person to be able to perform their job, but not less.

Comment: Thank you all, I figured it out, it turns out that this needs to be done from Windows Server 2008 R2 itself, where there is a Tsconfig.msc snap-in, it turns out that if you register it in newer versions, it does not transfer the security tab

Answer (score 0):

RDSConfig

> RDSConfig (the RDS Configuration Tool) that allows you to adjust RDP permissions on a very granular basis. You can add/remove accounts to the Remote Desktop Protocol ACL (Access Control List), adjust their permissions granularly (just like the old TSConfig.msc tool), but you can also do some cool new things, like quickly add users with permission presets (e.g. Guest, Standard, or Full Control/Admin), or completely reset the RDP Access Control List back to the “out of the box” defaults.

https://purerds.org/remote-desktop-free-tools/adjust-rdp-permissions-brand-new-free-tool/